# Estimation of investment adjustment costs

Tags: macroeconomics, regression, investment

Hi I am working on a problem set in my macroeconomics course. I have a hard time figuring out how to get started on one of the problems.

The set-up is the following. A price-taking firm maximizes:

$\max_{L_{t},K_{t},I_{t}} E_{0} [\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\prod_{s=0}^{t}(1+r_{s})^{-1}\{(1-\tau)K_{t}^{\alpha}L_{t}^{1-\alpha}-w_{t}L_{t}-I_{t}(1+a(I_{t}/K_{t}-\delta)) \}]$

subject to:

$K_{t} = (1-\delta)K_{t-1}+I_{t-1}$.

$K_{0}$ is given, $w_{t},r_{t}$ are stochastic, $\delta$ is the rate of capital depriciation, $I$ is the gross investment.

**The question is the following:**
Let $q$   be  the  Lagrange  multiplier  on  the  constraint  (it’s  also  Tobin’s  Q).  Derive  the  first  order conditions for optimization with respect to $L, I$ and $K$. Given $q$, what information is needed  to  establish  optimal  level  of  investment?  Log-linearize  the  FOC  for  investment.  Suppose  we  observe  $I, K$,  and  $q$. How  would  you  estimate  the  parameter  $a$ using  this  equation?  How  would  you  interpret  the  error  term  in  this  regression?  What  are  the  properties  of  the  error  term  given  your  interpretation  (e.g.,  serial  correlation,  correlation  with other variables, etc.)?

I have set up the Lagrangian setting $\prod_{s=0}^{t}(1+r_{s})^{-1}=R_{t}$:

$       \mathcal{L} =  E_{0} \big\{ \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} R_{t} \left[ (1-\tau)K_{t}^{\alpha}L_{t}^{1-\alpha} -w_{t}L_{t} -I_{t}(1+a(\frac{I_{t}}{K_{t}}-\delta)) + q_{t}(-K_{t}+(1-\delta)K_{t-1}+I_{t-1}) \right]\big\}$

and derived the following FOCs:

$        \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial L_{t}} = R_{t} \left[ (1-\tau)(1-\alpha)K_{t}^{\alpha}L_{t}^{-\alpha}-w_{t} \right]  = 0 \Leftrightarrow W_{t} = MPL_{t},\\
        \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial I_{t}} = R_{t} \left[ -1 -2a \frac{I_{t}}{K_{t}} + a\delta \right]  +E_{t}[R_{t+1}q_{t+1}]  = 0  \Leftrightarrow 1 +2a \frac{I_{t}}{K_{t}} - a\delta  = E_{t}[(1+r_{t+1})^{-1} q_{t+1}],\\
        \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial K_{t}} = R_{t} \left[ (1-\tau) \alpha K_{t}^{\alpha-1}L_{t}^{1-\alpha} + a \left( \frac{I_{t}}{K_{t}} \right)^{2} - q_{t} \right]  +E_{t}[R_{t+1}q_{t+1}(1-\delta)]  = 0, \\
         \Leftrightarrow  (1-\delta)^{-1}(q_{t}-(1-\tau) \alpha K_{t}^{\alpha-1}L_{t}^{1-\alpha} - a \left( \frac{I_{t}}{K_{t}} \right)^{2})  = E_{t}[(1+r_{t+1})^{-1} q_{t+1}].$

But I have a hard time seeing how I would log-linearize $1 +2a \frac{I_{t}}{K_{t}} - a\delta  = E_{t}[(1+r_{t+1})^{-1} q_{t+1}]$ to something useful in terms of a regression. I hope somebody can help explain how I should go from here? or if I have made a misstake in my derivations.